# Which encryption / encoding that starts with 'FU' ends with '=='? Or start with '\x' (backslash x)

Tags: encryption, encoding, character-encoding, cryptography, encode

I just want to decrypt / decode this string: `FU0UCBIEERoBAUZdUF1RDg==`

But I don't know which encryption / encoding that being used here.

I tried to use base64decode, it's resulting `\x15M\x14\b\x12\x04\x11\x1A\x01\x01F]P]Q\x0E`
Which has '\x' in the word

But I really sure that the result must be in a JSON formatted string. example: `{"position":999}`

Thank you

Comment: *Which encryption / encoding that starts with 'FU' ends with '=='?* - The first characters of an encoded string (e.g. Base64) are determined by the first bytes of the original data. You can't generally say that a string in X encoding always starts with this or that character. Also on the end, a base64 string can have 0, 1 or 2 '=='. Regarding the decoding, '\x' just means that the following number is a hex number, because there's no printable character for '\x15'. Your string could be the base64 encoded result of a hash or encryption.

Comment: @jps Thanks for the explanation! 1 more question. how do you know if \x15 is not a printable character?

Comment: look into an [ASCII-Table](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:ASCII-Table-wide.svg). Byte value 00 to 1F are non printable.